# How to make the loop to change the url

Tags: php, regex, loops, for-loop

Basically I'm trying to parse IMDB ID from the urls given. Trying to make a loop to change the page number and continue scraping for IMDB TTs.

I'm expecting variable $page to increment by 1, so the $url will change and the foreach function in every loop will receive a new url and start scraping again.

**But the problem is:** The loop only parsing one page unlimited times, the page number is not increasing by 1.

```
   $url   = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=animation&page='.$page.''; # this URL

for ($page = 1; $page <= 5 ; $page++) {

foreach((new DOMXpath(@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url)))->query($expr) as $obj)
    preg_match($regex, $obj->value, $matches)
      && $ids[$matches[$match]] = 0;
    ;
$ids = array_keys($ids);


    print implode("<br /> ", $ids);

}
```

Example: http://surveygun.com/tt.php

Comment: Have you tried defining the `$url` inside your for-loop?

Comment: Yes, I did. Getting the same results as it's was outside the loop.

Comment: This makes no sense, can't decipher what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hardly possible that you would get the same results if you assigned the value of $url inside the for loop. But that your last echo _after_ the outer loop only ever outputs one URL is of course no surprise. (If it ever outputs anything at all - seems you are not ending the for loop on your own, but waiting for either run time or memory limit to kill it ...?)

Comment: The first thing you should do, is format your code properly - proper indenting, and {} after _every_ if/else/loop statement. (If you feel like you need to question why, go research.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, change $i <= num to how every many pages you want to loop through.

```
for( $i= 1 ; $i <= 165 ; $i++ ){
  $url   = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=animation&page='.$i.'';

  // some code here

  sleep(2);
}
```

UPDATE(no dupes):

```
<?php
 for( $i= 1 ; $i <= 5 ; $i++ ){
 $url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=animation&page=$i";
 $page = file_get_contents($url);
   preg_match_all("/id=\"sb_(tt\d{7})/", $page, $idinfo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
   foreach($idinfo as $idnumber){
   $idnumber = $idnumber[1];
   echo $idnumber.'<br>';
 }}
?>
```

You might consider putting a sleep in between loops as a polite measure ie sleep(2); this would put it to sleep for 2 secs.

Comment: It's solved 1 problem, the loop is stopping when I need it. But still continuing to parse only first page. Here is an example http://surveygun.com/tt.php

Comment: What is it you are trying to parse? IMDB has an api you can use as well.

Comment: I'm trying to parse IMDB IDs like tt0286716 which is assigned for every movie

Comment: gotcha, give me one sec as I look at the source code.

Comment: @AdamS. so I tested this and it returns 5 pages at 400+ ids per page. That is based on me using $i <= 5. You can use how ever many pages as you choose.

Comment: I thought maybe I was stupid, but I understand that I'm just not qualified yet. Need to learn and learn. Your code is working perfectly. I will try to implement the "array_unique" to remove the duplicates, but you Norcal really made my day. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: You are most definitely not stupid :) We all have a lot to learn and I am sure there more than one way to all these answers. Just use what makes sense to you so you can grow from it. Try finding someone on youtube that is comfortable for you to follow and so you can see it build hands on. Anyhow good luck, cheers :)

Comment: @AdamS. I didnt realize they have dupes on those pages, check on the new, new update to get only singles. Cheers